# Specify my own message-id header when sending email with cdo.message

Tags: asp-classic, cdo.message

Is there a way to specifty my own message-id with CDO ?

Using the following configuration, the message-id is still generated by the cdo component and ignores the one I specified.

```
<%
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2

Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

' set the CDOSYS configuration fields to use port 25 on the SMTP server
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp@example.com"

    .Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:message-id") = "0123456789.0123456789@example.com"
.Update
End With

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf

    .From = "from@example.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .To = "to@example.com"
    .HTMLBody = "test"
    .Send
End With
Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Set Flds = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The configuration object `iConf` is irrelevant to the message object `iMsg`, 
you don't need to create it.</strike>

<strike>So, remove `Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")` and replace `Set Flds = iConf.Fields` with `Set Flds = iMsg.Fields`.</strike>

You need to use `iMsg.Fields` to set headers for the message.

[Setting Message Header Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms988660(v=exchg.65).aspx)

```vb
Dim iMsg, iConf, Flds
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set Flds = iMsg.Fields
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConf.Fields

' set the CDOSYS configuration fields to use port 25 on the SMTP server
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.example.com"
    .Update
End With

With iMsg.Fields
    .Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:message-id") = "0123456789.0123456789@example.com"
    .Update
End With

With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf

    .From = "from@example.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .To = "to@example.com"
    .HTMLBody = "test"
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: I updated my code example to show what I do later with iConf (put in iMsg.Configuration).
If I try not using it like you suggest I get an error: "The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid."

Comment: got it working, I needed to set sendusing and smtpserver configuration in iMsg.Configuration.Fields instead of iMsg.Fields.

I receive my message-id now, please update your code solution and I'll mark your answer as the solution

Comment: @Jonathan you're right, updated the answer.

Comment: You've [already answered this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19184371/692942) previously.

Comment: @Lankymart I beleive I can find another one.

Comment: I found that I needed to put enclosing chevrons in the value: `.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:message-id") = "<0123456789.0123456789@example.com>"`