# How to request read receipt using CDO Email in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, receipt, cdo.message

When composing an email using the Gmail email service there's an option to request read receipt.

Is it possible to request it when creating an email using the CDO library?

I tried sending an email from and to myself with `Fields(CDO.CdoMailHeader.cdoReturnReceiptTo) = From` but the email sent didn't requested read receipt.

Excel VBA code in a module:

```
' VBA project name:
' VBAProject

' Microsoft Excel 2013 built-in references:
' Excel - Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
' VBA - Visual Basic For Applications

' Aditional references:
' ADODB - Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
' CDO - Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library

Option Explicit

Private Sub SendMail( _
  ByVal ConnectionTimeout As Long, _
  ByVal Server As String, _
  ByVal Port As Long, _
  ByVal UseSSL As Boolean, _
  ByVal From As String, _
  ByVal MessageTo As String, _
  ByVal Subject As String, _
  ByVal UseHTML As Boolean, _
  ByVal HTMLBody As String, _
  ByVal TextBody As String)

  Dim Message As CDO.Message
  Dim Configuration As CDO.Configuration
  Dim Fields As ADODB.Fields

  Set Message = New CDO.Message
  Set Configuration = Message.Configuration
  Set Fields = Configuration.Fields

  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSendUsingMethod) = CDO.CdoSendUsing.cdoSendUsingPort
  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = CDO.CdoProtocolsAuthentication.cdoBasic
  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = ConnectionTimeout
  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSMTPServer) = Server
  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSMTPServerPort) = Port
  Fields(CDO.CdoConfiguration.cdoSMTPUseSSL) = UseSSL
  Fields.Update

  Message.BodyPart.Charset = CDO.CdoCharset.cdoUTF_8
  Message.From = From
  Message.To = MessageTo
  Message.Subject = Subject
  If UseHTML Then
    Message.HTMLBody = HTMLBody
  Else
    Message.TextBody = TextBody
  End If
  Message.Send

End Sub
```

Comment: This link https://forums.asp.net/t/1064087.aspx?How+to+request+a+read+receipt+sending+SMTP+form+emails+ says you have to "specify a Disposition-Notification-To header.". This link suggests how that might be done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183209/add-extra-header-to-email-vb-asp-3-0-script

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried `Message.Fields("Disposition-Notification-To") = From` as well as `Configuration.Fields` and `CDO.CdoMailHeader.cdoDispositionNotificationTo` but the email didn't had request read receipt.

Comment: Have you tested just manually sending an email through gmail? This https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9413651?hl=en says read receipts don't work in gmail if it's basically a personal address.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Using Gmail when I [send](https://i.imgur.com/yk9YOFZ.png) from email1 to itself I get [this](https://i.imgur.com/tqA3uYh.png) but when I send to email2 it doesn't show anything just like when I sent an email through the code (email1 is `@<workplace's domain>.com` and email2 is `@gmail.com`).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid None of my attempts in gmail or with code gave me the option to return the read receipt and I didn't received any receipts.